# get_absolute_url returns an empty string/object has no attribute

Tags: python, django, django-models

http://pastebin.com/H7n1Juv0 
http://pastebin.com/hJvcAdBG # full model, if needed..
How can I fix this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `get_absolute_url` method must be present directly in your Model class (is nested a level deeper than necessary, thus being part of your `save` method).